# How many types of constructors are there in php

Tags: php, constructor

I know the following types of constructors in OOPS:

- Parameterized
- Default
- Copy

But i am not sure whether php supports all of these. What are the types of constructors that are supported in php

Comment: why not try yourself ?

Comment: I tried copy , doesn't works without any workaround. simply, i need some confirmation about it whether if i am missing something :)

Comment: check this http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.cloning.php for copy constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP supports all of them:

```
class A {
    // default is a build-in non-parametrized one

    public function __construct(/* arguments */){
        // parametrized
    }

    public function __clone(){
        // copy
    }
}

// if __construct() is not declared, then uses default one:
$a = new A;

// if __construct() is declared, then uses parametrized one:
$a = new A(/* arguments */);

// if __clone() is declared, then uses copy one:
$b = clone $a;
```

References:

1. [Constructors and Destructors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php).
2. [Object cloning](http://php.net/clone).